# Current through grounded conductor in uniform electric field

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, electrons, electromagnetic-induction, conductors

I want to know that, if we place a conductor inside of uniform external electric field then opposite charges will get induced on the both sides of conductor, so what if we connect two earth wire to each side, will continuous current will flow through the conductor? As from the positive charge induced side will take electron from ground and negative charge induced side will eject electron so will continuous flow of current is seen in this case?[image]

Answer (score 1):

The ground is also a large conductor, so you can get surface charges induced on the wires and on the ground itself. These surface charges will quickly distribute to make the E field 0 inside the conductor (including the ground). There will then not be a continual current.