# Potential difference between opposite sides of same conductor inside electric field

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, voltage, conductors

What is the potential difference between the two opposite sides of plate conductor placed in uniform electric field(E) and let say +q and -q induced charges are at opposite sides of a conductor having width "d"? Will there be potential difference between the opposite sides of same conductor in uniform electric field?
Can I treat two sides as two plates which are opposite at a distance " d"? [image]

Comment: The charges move so as to cancel any field inside the material (providing that the charges can move). No more and no less. So, no, there is no potential difference.

Answer (score 1):

After the field from the external source is applied, free charges in the conductor will move in such a way as to produce an opposing field. You have shown this correctly on your diagram. In a very short time equilibrium will be reached when the resultant electric field in the conductor is zero. Therefore no electrical work would be done taking a test charge between any two points in the conductor. So there will be no potential difference between any two points. If the field strength were anything other than zero, the free charges would still be moving and we wouldn't have equilibrium!

"Can I treat two sides as two plates which are opposite at a distance "d"?" Yes, you could compare the set-up to a capacitor with dielectric of infinite relative permittivity, but don't forget that the plates wouldn't have charges were it not for the external field.

Comment: Would you please consider this question also:-https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/684147/current-through-grounded-conductor-in-uniform-electric-field/684178#684178

Comment: Please consider this question also, it's related to this one     https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/600864/does-current-flow-from-earth-connected-conductor-in-uniform-electric-field/600870#600870